# Base64 encode uploaded file then save in database

Tags: php

I want to base 64 encode uploaded file then save this into Blob type column of a table in MySQL database.

I have tried built in PHP function base64_encode with file variable but this does not seem to work.

Is there a way we can do this?

The reason is that I do not want to use moveuploaded file into a folder.

Thank you.

Comment: You don't have to base64_encode a file before storing it in a blob.

Comment: How do you save in a table then?

Comment: you can simply insert the file data into your blob field.

Comment: "The reason is that I do not want to use moveuploaded file into a folder." --- actually it is not the *reason*. *Reason* is what caused that

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As @Sjoerd and @zerkms correctly point out, you do not need to do this - a blob column is be used to store raw binary data, so you can bypass the Base64 process and insert the raw data of the file.

If you want to store images in a database (which, by the way, I personally don't like to do) it is better to store the raw data - Base64 encoding the data makes it larger, and means that it must be decoded before the image is rendered, which adds processing overhead.

This is how you can insert the raw binary data (assuming the MySQL extension):

```
$data = file_get_contents($_FILES['name_of_control']['tmp_name']);
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);

$query = "
  INSERT INTO table
    (`blob_column`)
  VALUES
    ('$data')
";

mysql_query($query);
```

If you really do want to Base64 encode it (in which case it could just be stored in a varchar), just just add a `base64_encode()` call:

```
$data = file_get_contents($_FILES['name_of_control']['tmp_name']);
$data = base64_encode($data);

// There is an argument that this is unnecessary with base64 encoded data, but
// better safe than sorry :)
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);

$query = "
  INSERT INTO table
    (`varchar_column`)
  VALUES
    ('$data')
";

mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: A question, Dave - you say that raw binary data can be stored directly in the BLOB field without using base64_encode. But isn't this susceptible to injection? And if you use mysql_real_escape_string, it seems to (irreversibly) corrupt certain common file types such as PDF. My impression so far is that base64_encode is the only way to both escape the file, and preserve the exact contents...?

Comment: to @TopherHunt: use prepared statements. ALL is safe then!