# Save Image as Blob in Db

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flash-cs5, blobstorage

In my application the user needs to register himself. In the proces he needs to take a picture. I would like to save the picture in the database. It's an Flex mobile project and I use php.
Here is what I've got so far:

In as:

```
   var bitmapdata:BitmapData=this.data as BitmapData;
   var encoder:JPEGEncoder=new JPEGEncoder(85);
   var stream:ByteArray=encoder.encode(bitmapdata);
   var b64:Base64Encoder=new Base64Encoder();
   b64.encodeBytes(stream);

   var obj:Object=new Object();
   obj.test="test";
   obj.bytes=b64;

   netCon=new NetConnection();
   netCon.connect(".../gateway.php");
   var resp:Responder=new Responder(resultHandler, faultHandler);
   netCon.call("gotcha.registerUserPic",resp,stream);
```

In php:

```
function registerUserPic($paramObj){
        $test=addslashes($paramObj['test']);
        $data=addslashes($paramObj['bytes']);
        $decodeddata=base64_decode($data);
        $sql="INSERT INTO `dbName`.`upload` (`id`,`content`) VALUES (NULL, '$decodeddata');";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        return $result;
        }
```

But he won't save the byteArray in the BLOB Field.

When I trace the b64 = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAUDBAQEAwUEBAQFBQUGBwwIBwcHBw8LCwkMEQ8SEhEP.. ."

I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: I can't see where you append encoder.encode() to your stream before b64encoding it...

Comment: var stream:ByteArray=encoder.encode(bitmapdata); I wrote this between var encoder... and var b64...

Comment: Hi @TimonDevos, something similar happened to me in flex-java, but the problem was in Java, because I had to insert a blob from ByteArray data (like your problem). Check this link, maybe help you: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559363/base64-encode-uploaded-file-then-save-in-database)