# how to upload Base_encode image on server using cake php

Tags: cakephp, base64, image-uploading

I received a image from Android in the format of base_encode. I am using following method to save image on server.Image uploaded on server successfully  but it upload image size of 0kb file

```
<?php
     $user_last_id = $this->User->getLastInsertID();
    if(@$_FILES['profile_image']!='') {  
      $img = base64_decode($_FILES['profile_image']['name']);
      $image_name =  $user_last_id.'_'.time()."profileImage.png";
      $this->User->saveField('profile_image',$image_name);
      $pth =  WWW_ROOT.'files'.DS.'profileimage'.DS.$image_name;
      file_put_contents($pth, $img);
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Probably because the string is not base64 encoded so decodes to an empty string, that or the key you're decoding (name) is the wrong one. You need to debug what's happening and/or provide enough information for a reader to reproduce what you're seeing.

Comment: In fact, that's probably directly the problem see for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/8559363/761202 - you are trying to decode the wrong thing (tmp_name is the key with the encoded string).